# Addition and product of two elements in a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Need some explanation on how the product is done below. 
I am not sure how they were able to simplify $x^5+2x^2$ to $-2x^2$, $x^3$ by $-2$ and then I'm just lost on how the product is done.

I thought it goes by a rule:

$(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I, I=<x^3+2>$

So may be:

$(x^5+x^2+I)(2x^2-x+3+I)=2x^7-x^6+3x^5+2x^4-2x^3+3x^2+I$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I think about *reduction by the ideal $I = (x^3 + 2)$* when I am computing something is to just substitute any factor $x^3$ by $-2$. The reason why this works is because in your quotient any multiple $x^3 +2 $ becomes zero, so in particular $x^3 + 2 \equiv 0 \mod I \implies x^3 \equiv -2 \mod I$.

So then $x^5 = x^3x^2 \equiv -2x^2 \mod I$.

In the computation of the product (which the author confusingly (mistakenly?) denotes by $+$ as well), a step is omitted which I think will provide a lot of clarity.

Namely, the product goes like this:
$$
(x^5 + x^2)(2x^2 - x + 3) \equiv (-x^2)(2x^2 - x + 3) \equiv -2x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 \equiv 4x - 2 - 3x^2 \mod I.
$$

Comment: If possible could you help explain what terms are interacting with what and how they are simplified for the product as well?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it.

Comment: Helps Ruben, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

$a+I=b+I $ if and only if  $a-b\in I $. Note that  $x^3+2$ is in $I $. So we have $x^3+I=-2+I $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I'd start with dividing $x^5+x^2$ into $x^3+2$ giving

$x^5+x^2 = x^2\cdot(x^3+2) - x^2.$

Then you just have to multiply $-x^2$ and $2x^2-x+3$ modulo $x^3+2$.